# jQuery button displayed on top of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, button

After calling .button() on my buttons, they are being displayed on top of my sub menu. To better explain, here's a screenshot:

[image]

I call my jQuery on my MasterPage:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (e) {
        $("button, input[type='button'], input[type='submit']").button(); 
    });
</script>
```

I'm referencing google's jQuery's 1.5 and 1.8 jquery script. (Otherwise my .button() doesn't work and get script errors such as 'Object [object Object] has no method button')

Why is this happening, and how can I change it?

Thanks.

Comment: you should override the CSS styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The depth involved with HTML elements is controlled by their individual `z-index` values. You'll need to go through your CSS to adjust these values (or dynamically change them using jQuery).

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index

Comment: Thanks - I changed the z-index of my menu.